# Floating Action Buttons are under AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a problem with layout.
I want an floating buttons on the borderline of a menu and pager area.
I have them in a right position, but problem is, that fabs are hiding under AppBar.

I was trying bringToFront at the end of onCreate call, but it is not working.

Bellow is screnshot and my layout code.

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/inv_main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="eu.donda.inventura.Inventura">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/inv_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/inv_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/inv_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/inv_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fab_holder"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/inv_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_scan_ean"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickEAN"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_barcode"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_scan_qr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickQR"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_qrcode"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_ocr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickOCR"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ocr"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickPhoto"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:onClick="onClickAdd"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
        </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: in your LinearLayout change this `app:layout_anchor="@id/inv_appbar"`  to this app:layout_anchor="@id/inv_tabs".

Comment: same result. FABs are still hiding

Comment: Wait I implement you code.

Comment: in your `FlotingActionButton` change this attribute `app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_qrcode"` to this `android:src="@mipmap/ic_recode`.

Comment: changing source is not working for me. I had some particular succes with CollapsingToolbarLayout. But there was problem with Tabs and a group with fabs. For single fabs it was working better.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your LinearLayout

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: This attribute moves fabs under appbar. This solve technical problem with user interaction. But design is not what i want.